# Is it safe to publicly expose key hashes?

Tags: passwords, key-management, api

I have a simple API which I want to limit users using a key. For each request, the users will need to post the key and the other parameters.

For example in R:

```
res <- httr::POST(
  "api-url",
  body = list(
    img = img,
    key = "6pX2PKIKTGyjORcUjlbyDv1yPyxDdk63LudskjdXnyx1tJ7mjhfmeYMTQ7gH8q376"
  ),
  encode = "json"
  )
```

The request handler will do the following:

```
 key <- openssl::sha256(key)
  if(!key %in% keys | is.null(key) | is.na(key)) {
    stop("Not authorized. Get an api key from decryptr.com.br")
  } else {
    return(result)
  }
```

My question is: Is it safe to let the `keys` object be public in order that anyone can read it?

At the moment it's a `yaml` file like this containing only the hashes for each key:

```
keys:
- ef556689177dbe281139a5688162f54166127c83746a83c87b872605621sa156
- b934527d8d59be4766e43db6c9de039871ddcea33c948bcf59ee5ed29fdr1f4f
```

Comment: Is the key the only thing you need to access the api, there's no client secret or other authentication? What are you protecting, do you care if people other than your intended users can pull data from the api? Can you write data using the api?

Comment: 1) The key is the only method. 2) The API is a simple algorithm that receives an image and returns it's content. The api doesn't write data. 3) I just want that only my costumers with the key can get the results from my API.

Comment: Unrelated security question: is there a reason why you're checking key presence in the authorized list *before* doing validity checks?  It seems to me that if a null key found its way into the list of valid keys, your code would permit people to use your API without a key, where checking in the opposite order would provide an extra layer of security.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the keys contain as many or more bits of entropy than the number of output bits of the hash (ie keys are random and long enough), making the hashes public wouldn't result in any notable loss of security. To reverse a hash of sufficiently random data would require a [preimage attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_attack), and preimage resistance is one of the basic properties of a cryptographic hash function (even MD5 is still preimage resistant). Just make sure the keys are being generated with a CSPRNG.

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvotes? If I'm wrong I would love to know why.

Comment: I'm not one of the people who downvoted, but I imagine it may be because making key hashes public allows them to be attacked. This isn't an issue if the key is generated randomly, but it is if the hash is of a user-supplied password. Releasing a hash of 16 bytes of random data is fine. Releasing a hash of "hunter2" is not.

Comment: @forest I thought I made it pretty clear that for this to be ok the key needs to be randomly generated. Suggestions to improve?

Comment: Well I think your answer is fine. I'm just guessing at why people might have downvoted (skimmed the answer and thought you were referring to regular password hashes).

Answer (score 2):

Ok, you only keep a hash of the secret on permanent storage, which is conformant with best practices. That being said, the *least priviledge principle* still recommends that access to a data should be restricted to roles requiring it. So in your use case, access to the file containing the hashes should be restricted to:

- the user(s) running the application
- the admins of the platform

If the hash is secure enough (and SHA256 has a pretty good reputation), it would be hard for an attacker to brute force it. But restricting access is just an additional defense line: an attacker will need a previous exploit to get the hashes.

To precisely answer your question, I would say that storage of hashes means that leaking the hashes file will not compromise the security provided you soon change the secrets, so it is safe. But it would be much safer to restrict access.

Comment: And this is one of those places where I'm conflicted. Obviously keeping the hashes secret can't make it any _less_ secure, but if the keys have 256 bits of entropy recommending to change them if a `SHA256` hash is leaked seems to me like pure paranoia.